# CSS height transition - wrong direction in chrome

Tags: css, reactjs, google-chrome, height

I'm using `react` with `react-collapse` to perform collapse transition on a div.
My use-case is that the element that toggles the collapsing is under the collapsing element.
When I toggle to collapse, in Chrome 84+ only, the transition happens above the element and does not push it down. In Firefox, for example, it does - and this is my desired behaviour.

Reproducing codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/angry-elion-dxi75?file=/src/App.js
Opening it in chrome 84+ will reproduce the bug.
Opening it in Safari/Firefox/Chrome 83- will present the desired behaviour.

My assumption is that something changed in chrome's way of doing this transition in the latest version and that it doesn't allow the toggling element to disappear from the visible DOM.
Am I correct?
Is there a way for me to get my desired behaviour?

Thank you very much, any help appreciated!

Saar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution is to add to any container above these elements:

```
  overflow-anchor: none;
```